# IPTV over router issue

Tags: networking, vlan, iptv, netgear-router

I have an issue with the IPTV box connected in my system. Ideally, the ISP provided setup should look like this:

[image]

How I have it connected is this way:

[image]

So in practice the gateway's WAN port is connected to the ISP provided LAN port. The address range there is 192.168.1.x. On the output of the gatway, there is a sub-network with 192.168.7.x address range- the IPTV device does not like that... The IPTV device is normally assigned with a valid address (192.168.7.x) and has internet access, but the channels are blocked. The ISP technician said it has to be in the ISP provided modem range.

Right now my gateway and the access points are the [Netgear Orbi RBK853](https://www.netgear.com/home/wifi/mesh/rbk853/) (1 main router + 2 satelites). It takes quite a while (in physical cables terms) for the ethernet connection to reach the IPTV box, since starting from the Orbi gateway there is a satelite (access point) and a switch (not drawn here). So the easiest solution, to connect the IPTV directly to the ISP provided modem is not possible for me.

How to configure the gateway (if even possible), to somehow forward the packets from the ISP provided modem directly to the IPTV box without the NAT network created by the gateway, so the IPTV box gets assigned with an IP from the 192.168.1.x range (by the ISP provided modem), instead of 192.168.7.x (Orbi gateway).

PS: I have replaced the Wifi Mesh setup I had before with Orbi just now. Physically it was connected the same way and this worked- when I logged to the gateway interface I haven't seen the IPTV box- I have seen it via the ISP provided modem interface, so it was somehow forwarded.

I tried exercising VLAN approach, but if understood correctly, I would need to sacrifice one of the physical LAN ports of my gateway for that. Since at the given lan port more devices than just the IPTX box are connected, I could not go this way. I need more of a specific mac address oriented approach.

Comment: Why don't you set the DHCP subnet range for your router to  192.168.7.x instead of 192.168.1.x?

Comment: I guess you mean the way around (router is 7.x and modem is 1.x). The reason is that I have around 50-60 devices connected in the network. many of them have hardcoded IP addresses of the other devices they communicate with. When I replaced the router I had to manually preserve the whole reservation list, which was in the 192.168.7.x range in the old router...

Comment: If the ISP provided box assigns the device connected to it, an ip address in the range of 192.168.7.2 and  192.168.7.255 all you have to do is assigned the DHCP range  192.168.7.3 to 192.168.7.255.  Sounds like you need a switch allowing you to connect multiple devices to your lan port assuming the ISP modem supports that

Comment: Yes the ISP modem has 4 lan ports- I connect one of them to my routers WAN. Ok, so to summarize, instead of tempering with my router settings, I should change the ISP modem settings, so it works in the 192.168.7.x range as well, but outside of the one the router does? So say router has an IP of 192.168.7.1 and gives the range from 7.2 to 7.240 + the ISP modem has 192.168.7.241 and gives a range of 7.242-7.250? Does that make sense?

Comment: Your ISP modem is already assuming DHCP address at that range based on the description of your problem. Furthermore, most of the time, ISP modems only provision limited number of devices over Ethernet

Comment: Multicast doesn't work well over WiFi without workarounds which have the downside of flooding the airwaves with potentially unnecessary traffic. Presumably there is a WiFi (? wireless ethernet) step in there as you have an access point in the chart

Comment: Yes the Orbi router has 2 satelites connected (access points). Together they form a Wifi mesh. But the Wifi part doesn't play any role in here, as the IPTV is connected via ethernet cable, just through some switches and the access point, which works as a switch as well.

Comment: @Ramhound The ISP modem range is 192.168.1.10 - 192.168.1.150. The router's range is 192.168.7.2 - 192.168.7.250. What I was thinking here is to leave alone the router and change the IPS modem range and IP.

Comment: So what range does the IPTV require to function? Your question isn't clear in this regard. You should be able to modify the DHCP of the ISP modem to be significantly smaller and increase the Orbi to support more devices.

Comment: At this point I don't think its about the range or exact IP address specifically. Its about the IPTV to be connected directly yo the ISP modem. The question is whether a router/ gateway that is in between, can somehow provide that raw route via software? AFAIK this could be accomplished via VLAN, but this would require sacrificing one whole LAN port of the gateway.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect it's not just the IP address; with many ISPs it's also the ability to receive *multicast* packets – the IPTV box sends an IGMP 'join' packet for a channel, the router forwards it up to the ISP, and you start receiving the stream for that particular channel much like a TV signal.

When that's the case, "having a 192.168.1 address" is not actually what's needed – it's a stand-in for "being directly in the ISP-router's own subnet"; looking at the IP address is merely a way of telling whether the device is in the right subnet or not.

(And *that* is still not the full story; really it can be in a different subnet as long as all routers in the way can forward IGMP towards the 'WAN' side and can forward multicast from 'WAN' back to the IPTV box.)

The above is not always the same for all ISPs (some use multicast and some don't), but it's rather common – so common in fact that many home routers even have the "IGMP proxy" ability even if they're otherwise entirely lacking in features. So the first thing I'd suggest trying is to enable "IGMP proxy" on your router and see if that helps.

> How to configure the gateway (if even possible), to somehow forward the packets from the ISP provided modem directly to the IPTV box without the NAT network created by the gateway, so the IPTV box gets assigned with an IP from the 192.168.1.x range (by the ISP provided modem), instead of 192.168.7.x (Orbi gateway).

While *technically* possible, it's a lot of configuration that often isn't even available on home routers, and it'll really be easier to use VLANs.

> I tried exercising VLAN approach, but if understood correctly, I would need to sacrifice one of the physical LAN ports of my gateway for that. Since at the given lan port more devices than just the IPTX box are connected, I could not go this way.

No, literally the whole point of VLANs is usually that you can have multiple on the same port. It will be the job of a (smart) switch connected to that port to demultiplex the VLANs, assigning some of the switch ports to the "192.168.7" VLAN and some to the "passthrough to ISP" VLAN.

Comment: 1. The Orbi router does support IGMP proxy it seems by default, as the only options I have is to a) disable it, b) set a version of it (auto, V1 or V2), or add PCCW IGMP proxying (I have no idea whats that). Even with the last one set, it does not work. 2. Ok so how can I make this config target my IPTV box only based on its MAC and threat other devices connected to that lan normally?

Comment: I am not sure, but I think that would be necessary is "MAC address based VLAN", where as it seems that the Orbi router only supports "interface based VLAN"...